# Understanding conversion from float to np.uint8 for python

Tags: python, python-2.7, type-conversion

I am running Python 2.7 script and recently i had this conversion problem when going from a float to uint8 where a negative value was not clip to 0 but to 256 - value.

simplifying the code i have, it could look something like this

```
a = -72.0
b = np.array(a, dtype=np.uint8)
c = np.array(np.clip(a,0,255),dtype=np.uint8)

print 'a =',a, 'b =',b, 'c =', c

a = -72.0 b = 184 c = 0
```

I am just trying to understand why b was not set to 0, but it rolled over to be 256-72=184 instead.
If anybody has an explanation or a good link on data type that i can read that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe i found my own answer, it is simply related of how signed and unsigned number are interpreted in binary.
So when I go from a signed -72 to unsigned because of the uint8 they are both written in the same way at the binary level. Just that one read -72 and the other is +184